# How to get Drop Down List Attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down list on a webpage called ddlPaymentType. When I load this drop down I am adding a style attribute to each value.

C# line is:

```
ddlPaymentType.Items[i].Attributes.Add("status", statusValue);
```

I am trying to get this style value  in my javascript function.

```
function PaymentTypeChange() {
    var ddlType = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlPaymentType");
    var selItem = ddlType.selectedIndex;
    var ddlStatus = ddlType.options[selItem].status;
}
```

The ddlType is finding the control. But I can't get that attribute.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign attribute to option and want to get from selected option you can do something like

```
$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlPaymentType option:selected').attr('status');
```

*Or*

```
$('#<%= ddlPaymentType.ClientID %> option:selected').attr('status');
```

Comment: Awesome.  The first line worked, the second did not.   Thanks for your help!